# expo web hide bottom navigation bar when keyboard show

Tags: android, react-native, expo, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I would like to hide my bottom navigation bar on mobile device when keyboard is show.
I use Expo 40
I have added in definition option bottom bar **keyboardHidesTabBar: true**, such as:

```
const TabBot = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();
...
return(
    <TabBot.Navigator 
      initialRouteName="np"
      tabBarOptions={{
        keyboardHidesTabBar: true
      }}
      barStyle={TabBotOpt}>
...
```

I have add **"softwareKeyboardLayoutMode": "pan"** in android section into app.json file,
but when I open the website from mobile phone (android) I have this:

[image]

It is possible to hide bottom Tab Navigation when keyboard is open?